# Python FOR Loop using generated strings

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to get this code run in python:

```
line1 = 'a'
line2 = 'b'
line3 = 'c'
for i in range (1,4):
    word = 'line' + str(i)
    print (word)
```

The desired result should be a,b,c
Any help would be apreciated

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? `str()` is inappropriate as you aren't trying to get the string representation of that number. Why not use an array?

Comment: You can't just invent semantics. Perhaps read the tutorial first..?

Comment: ANY TIME you find yourself with variables of the form `xxx1`, `xxx2`, `xxx3` etc., you need to replace that set with a list.  What you're trying to do here (refer to variable names indirectly) is simply not good practice in Python.  There are ways to do it, but they are intended for special circumstances, and this is not special.

Comment: Not my downvote, but that doesn't show any effort. It's unclear what the *actual* question is too - pick a string based on a number? Or use letters instead of numbers? In which case, what happens when you go past `z`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Couldn't you use a `dict` instead?

Comment: Thanks to everybody for trying helping me. I am shure that there are plenty of better solutions for resolving the problem. I got it work with:
word = eval('line' + str(i))

Answer (score 0):

You can't call variable names using Strings. The current way you have it, you're assigning word to the actual String "line1" "line2" etc., this won't have anything to do with the variables line1, line2, line3.

To do what you're trying to accomplish, I recommend making a list with the variables as such:

```
line1 = 'a'
line2 = 'b'
line3 = 'c'
word = ""

lines = [line1, line2, line3]

for i in range(len(lines)):
    word = lines[i]
    print (word)
```

This is a pretty fundamental (but normal) error for beginners. I recommend reading the Python tutorial regarding Strings.

Comment: `for i in range(len(xxx)):` is another signal of unPythonic coding.  `for word in lines:` would be far better and more Pythonic.  Even better is `print(','.join(lines))`.

Comment: Correct. Wanted to keep it as understandable as possible for OP as they seem to want to use range.